# Unable to resize home and root partition(18.04)

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, hard-drive, resize

My laptop is dual booted with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. Recently I was pulling a docker image repository(which is around 15GB in total). My explorer showed that I do not have enough space available. I then opened GParted and saw my home directory has 36.2 GB free, but root directory has only 250 MB free. So I thought of reducing the home directory and expanding the root. But when I tried it to resize, I was unable to do so. I couldn't drag the bar nor was I able to enter any value. I've also attached an image of the same. Please suggest a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no image attached so this is a guess.

You cannot change the size of partitions that are mounted (i.e. in use). This state is indicated by a padlock icon in `gparted`.

You must boot into a live system (for example, a USB) in order to perform these operations.

***Backup your data before performing any partition operations.***